# Should c++ object files be linked through g++ only?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I read somewhere that c++ object files must be linked only through g++ not gcc. Is it true? if yes, then how to link object files belong to c, c++ and asm?

Answer (score 6):

If you use `g++` to link, then it will automatically link with the C++ runtime library. If you link with `gcc` you have to link with the runtime manually.

That's the only difference.

---

The `gcc` and `g++` programs are only special front-end wrapper programs, that invoke the correct preprocessor, compiler, assembler and linker for the files provided.

Comment: What is the C++ runtime library that we get. I have libstdc++.a in my toolchain. Is this what you are talking?

Comment: @vimalprathap Yes that's the library. You can use `gcc` if you want, even when linking C++ object files, if you just append `-lstdc++`.

Comment: Note that `g++` will **also** link in the C Standard Library. Assembly of course has no standard library itself, but you can call C and C++ Standard Library functions from assembly if you know the ABI.

Comment: You will need to assemble the .s files (nasm or something) to turn them into binary .obj files, and then you can link those too. C and C++ share a common ABI which allows exactly for this sort of thing.

Comment: @kfsone The `gcc` and `g++` wrapper programs are capable of invoking the system `as` assembler for `.s` files, for `.S` files it even invokes the pre-processor first.

Comment: D'oh; so long since I wrote a .s file myself I'd actually compartmentalized  compiler generated intermediates as something distinct, lol!

Comment: @kfsone Well you *might* have to call your own assembler, because on the x86 (and x86_64) platforms the standard `as` assembler is usually the [GNU binutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/) assembler, which uses AT&T syntax instead of Intel syntax for assembler files.

Comment: @Joachim I compiled each c and c++ modules(say C and CPP) independently with gcc and created .obj files seperately by using gcc to link the .o's to create libC.obj and libCPP.obj. As a final step i linked both  libC.obj and libCPP.obj along with libstdc++.a, using ld tool. Is this a valid procedure? because i end up in lot of linking errors related to c++.

Comment: @vimalprathap You should not link one set of object files into another object file. Instead you take *all* the generated object files and link into the final executable with all libraries. Other than that it's about the same procedure `g++` (or `gcc`) does. But I have to ask you, why do you use `ld` when linking, providing the C++ runtime library manually? There's no need for that. Compile each C, C++ and assembler source file into its corresponding object file, then simply use `g++` to link all of the object files and let `g++` handle everything.

Answer (score -4):

<s>Yes, you have to use G++ to link C++ due to name mangling.
See the topic here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling</s>

C++ names are C-abi compatible, you can link C++ object files to C code.

Comment: But my code has c, c++ ans .s files. How to link the objects in such case?

Comment: I suppose I'd go with g++, because C++ is able to link asm and C code. But @Joachim Pileborg has good point actually, just be sure to run C++ linker. I'm not sure how it works with C linking C++ object files/libs though..

Comment: @LukasT If you read your own reference and compare it to this question you'll realize that GCC/G++ mangle things the same way.  This answer is wrong.

Comment: @MohitJain: Yes, names are mangled at compile time, but when you want to link C-compiled code to C++, you need to hint C++ compiler that this C function name is mangled using C compiler.